# How to write simple RESTful PHP API

Tags: php, rest, api

I am new to PHP programming, but I am developing an iOS application which needs a small web-service. I would like to make it RESTful, because I read that that is the way to go.

So, could some one explain to me how I would go about doing this?

Let's say I have a database with users.

I know that with a good a REST API, to get all users I would need to call `GET api/users` for example.

What I do not understand is how do I create this? Do I make a folder on my server named api and a single php file named users which returns the users for me? Or is the php file named api and I am passing users as a parameter?

Again, what if I want to get a specific user?

I would do `GET api/users/23`. But do I create a new php file for every user and name it the user id (23 in this case)? Or how do I return user 23 to the API?

Could someone clarify these for me?

Answer (score 1):

You can refer this,

API/user.php

```
<?php
include("connection.php"); //Connect to database
$response = array();
 if(isSet($_POST['token']))
 {
    $select = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM `users`"); //Fetch all the user records
    if($select != false)
    {
        if($select != false && mysqli_num_rows($select) > 0)
        {
            while($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($select))
            {
                $response['status'] = true;
                $response['data'] = print_r($rows,true);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $response["status"] = false;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $response["status"] = false;
    }
}
else
{
    $response["status"] = false; //Unauthorized Access
}

echo json_encode($response);
mysqli_close($conn);

?>
```

API/connection.php

```
<?php
    $conn = mysqli_connect("HostName","UserName","password","DBName") or die("Some error occurred during connection " . mysqli_error($con));  
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Also consider to use the API framework, because you'll meet the problems which was already solved by framework's creators. F.e. look here: http://www.gajotres.net/best-available-php-restful-micro-frameworks/

Comment: Thank you, but I would like to first understand how REST works

Answer (score 0):

In general you'll redirect every single request to your main file `index.php` (using an `.htaccess` file) that will then call a "router".

This router will see the requests informations (the URL and the verb, `GET`, `POST`, ...) and call the corresponding function that you defined for this request.

This means that you're free to use any architecture, and not have your folders be organized the same ways as your route.

I'd recommend using a simple framework that will handle just the routing of the requests, it should give you all the keys to understand how it works. For example :

- http://altorouter.com/
- https://lumen.laravel.com/ (more than just a router, but still simple)

The simplest version of a router would be just conditions handling the various cases:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "GET" && $_SERVER[REQUEST_URI] == "/users") // request is GET /users
{
    // return the list of all users
}
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "GET" && preg_match('#/users/[0-9]+#', $_SERVER[REQUEST_URI])) // request is GET /users/[0-9]+
{
    // return a specific user
}
```